# Silverlight Binding question

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a stack panel and I have set its datacontext to my custom object "Questions" path in binding and I am adding framework elements at runtime and set the textblock's property to Binding(), it shows QuestionAnswer as object. I want to show the QuestionText. Is it becuase the class is abstract?
I have a few classes which inherit from QuestionAnswer like TextBoxQuestionAnswer,CheckboxQuestionAnswer etc.

When I try using Binding("TextBoxQuestionAnswer.QuestionText") nothing displays on the screen

```
public class Page
{
        public int PageID { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<QuestionAnswer> Questions { get; set; }
}

public abstract class QuestionAnswer
    {
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> AnswerOptions { get; set; }
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
        public AnswerResponse AnswerResponse { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are to the names of properties, not to class names so `Binding("TextBoxQuestionAnswer.QuestionText")` is not valid.

A stack panel is not much use for binding to a collection. You need a container that has an item template so you can get per item binding to a collection (listbox, grid etc).

We really need to see your Xaml and binding code to clarify this.